# Showing that $\sqrt[3]{x + \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{6^3} + x^2}} + \sqrt[3]{x - \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{6^3} + x^2}}$ is bounded by 4

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to show that 4 is an upper bound for $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x + \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{6^3} + x^2}} + \sqrt[3]{x - \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{6^3} + x^2}}$. This can easily be seen using tools like WolframAlpha. However, I'd like to show this analytically. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Edit:

- The function also has a lower bound of $-12$ but we only care about the upper bound.
- The function is not defined for x < -216 as $\frac{x^3}{6^3} + x^2$ becomes negative for those $x$ values. We are mainly concerned with $x > 0$.
- If we can show that this function is increasing, then using the Taylor expansion of the function at $\infty$ we can show that it is indeed bounded by 4.

Comment: Is this bounded above or below? Can you explain what happens with say $x = 0$ and $ x = 100$?

Comment: Hint: $\,f\,$ is increasing and $\,\left(f(x)\right)^3 = 2 x - \frac{1}{2} x f(x)$.

Comment: @dxiv Ok, I thought about using a similar approach. But how do you even show that this function is increasing?

Comment: @CalvinLin Technically, it's bounded below by -12 and above by 4. But I only care about the upper bound. At $x=0$, the function is 0 and at $x=100$ it's near $\approx 3.29$.

Comment: @Rie-man Maybe you could show that $f'(x)=0$ has no roots so it keeps the same sign, though there would be some calculations involved.

Comment: @dxiv If we take the derivative and gather all the terms under a common positive denominator, we get the following function in the numerator:
$\left(144\sqrt{6} x + \sqrt{6} x^2 + 24 \sqrt{x^2 (6^3 + x)}\right) \left(\sqrt[3]{
  x - \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{6^3} + x^2}}\right)^2 + \left(-144 \sqrt{6} x - \sqrt{6} x^2 + 24 \sqrt{x^2 (216 + x)}\right) \left(\sqrt[3]{
  x + \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{6^3} + x^2}}\right)^2$ which has similar issues.

Comment: What is the value of the function for $x<-216$?

Comment: @user It's undefined (at least in the reals) mainly because the function (which is in a square root) $\frac{x^3}{6^3} + x^2$ is negative for $x < -216$. But I don't even care about the negative values. All I care about is $x > 0$.

Comment: You did not point out the condition $x>0$ in the question.

Comment: @user It doesn't matter. I'm only concerned with the upper bound anyways.

Comment: @Rie-man Please edit the question to reflect these changes. Comments are intended to be ephemeral on MSE.

Comment: Is it not a coincidence that your function $f(x)$ is the expression one gets when solving the cubic equation in $t$: $t^3+\frac{x}{2}t-2x=0$, using Cardano's method? If $t=f(x)>4$ and $x>0$, then $0=t^3+\frac{x}{2}t-2x>64$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the identity $(a+b)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + 3ab(a+b)\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\left(f(x)\right)^3 &= \left(x + \cancel{\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{6^3} + x^2}}\,\right) + \left(x - \cancel{\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{6^3} + x^2}}\,\right)
 + 3 \sqrt[3]{\bcancel{x^2} - \left(\frac{x^3}{6^3} + \bcancel{x^2}\right)} \, f(x)
\\ &= 2 x - \frac{1}{2}\,x\, f(x)
\end{align}
$$

It is easily verified that $f(x) \gt 0$ on $\mathbb R^+$ and therefore:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\, x\, \big(4 - f(x)\big) = \big(f(x)\big)^3 \;\gt\; 0 \quad\implies\quad f(x) \,\lt\, 4 
$$

---

Though not used in the above, but since it was brought up both in OP's post and in comments, following is a proof that $f(x)$ is monotonic on $\mathbb R^+$.

Let:

$$
g(x) = f(6x) = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{x^3 + 36 x^2} + 6x} - \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{x^3 + 36 x^2} - 6x}
$$

Then:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
g'(x) = 0 \quad\quad\iff\quad\quad &\frac{x^2 + 24 x + 4 \sqrt{x^3 + 36 x^2}}{\cancel{2 \sqrt{x^3 + 36 x^2}} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{x^3 + 36 x^2} + 6x}^{\,2}} \\ =\, &\frac{x^2 + 24 x - 4 \sqrt{x^3 + 36 x^2}}{\cancel{2 \sqrt{x^3 + 36 x^2}} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{x^3 + 36 x^2} - 6x}^{\,2}}
\end{align}
$$

With $h(x) = \sqrt{x^3 + 36 x^2}\,$:

$$
(x^2 + 24 x + 4 h)^3 (h - 6x)^2 = (x^2 + 24 x - 4 h)^3 (h + 6x)^2
$$

After expanding, collecting and canceling:

$$
\cancel{8 h}\, (16 h^4 + 3 h^2 x^4 - 1152 h^2 x^2 - 3 x^7 - 108 x^6 + 20736 x^4) = 0
$$

Substituting $h^2(x) = x^3 + 36 x^2\,$:

$$
16 x^6 = 0
$$

It follows that $g'(x)$ does not change sign, so $g(x)$ is monotonic on $\mathbb R^+$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ Once either boundedness or monotonicity has been established, passing the equality $\,f(x) = 4 - \frac{2 \left(f(x)\right)^3}{x}\,$ to the limit $x \to\infty$ gives $\,\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 4\,$ so $4$ is a tight upper bound.

Comment: Is there any simple way to see $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(f(x)\right)^3}{x}=0$ ?

Comment: @user That follows once you proved either boundedness or monotonicity. If $f(x)$ is bounded then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x = 0$. If $f(x)$ is monotonic then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ must exist, and cannot be $+\infty$ because of the relation $x(4 - f)=2f^3$ so the limit must be finite and again  $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

It has been proved in the comment section and in the other answer that your sum function $f(x)$ verifies the equation:

$$f(x)^3+\frac x2f(x)-2x=0$$

Interestingly we can (magically$^*$) parametrise this as $\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{2t^3}{(t+16)^2}\\f(x)=\dfrac{4t}{t+16}\end{cases}$

It can easily be derivated and seen that $t\nearrow\implies x\nearrow$ and $f\nearrow$ strictly.

The bounds $t=-12\ (x=-216)$ and $t=+\infty\ (x=+\infty)$ then gives the interval $[-12,4)$ for $f$.

(*) in fact I have been inspired by a similar result I got recently totally unrelated to this problem, not on the net though ( i.e. $x^3+\frac ya x-ay=0$ gives $x=\frac{a^2t}{t+a^4},y=\frac{at^3}{(t+a^4)^2}$ )

Comment: That's some nice magic there (+1).